# Suppress Spotbugs warnings globally

Tags: java, spotbugs

I have one warning from spotbugs. This is suppressed with @SuppressFBWarnings in all those files.
I need to find a way to suppress this from one place so that I don't have to @SuppressFBWarnings in each file in that package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [filter file](https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filter.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindBugsFilter>
<Match>
  <Class name="my.package.*" />
</Match>
</FindBugsFilter>
```

This file can be given to spotbugs as command line argument `-exclude`, or if you are using an IDE it probably can be configured to be used somewhere.

This is especially useful when you want to exclude third-party code, or generated code, where you can't add the annotation to begin with. But it also helps separate the spotbugs configuration and the code.

Also note the `name` attribute can be a regular expression.

Comment: @ChitranshSaxena Sooo, if this answer helped your problem, will you accept it then? That way it is clear that the question has been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry I did not mark the answer as accepted, now I did. Thanks for pointing this out. Upon checking more, this was the most appropriate way to do it.